# How do I count the number of pageviews per day of the month in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Consider the following `pageviews` (left) and `daterange` (right) tables:

```
_date       pageviews       _date
---------------------       ----------
2011-01-01  21331           2011-01-01
2011-01-02  32143           2011-01-02
2011-01-04  23434           2011-01-03
.                           .
.                           .
2011-08-30  32322           2011-08-30
```

The table contains dates with corresponding website pageviews. Notice there are days without any pageviews (such as `2011-01-03`).

What I need is a query to count the total number of pageviews per day of the month. So it should add the number of pageviews of januari 1st + februari 1st + ... + november 1st as the first value, then januari 2 + februari 2 + ... februari 3 as the second value. The output of the query wuld thus be 31 days (numbered 1 to 31) with corresponding total number of pageviews.

I have no clue on how to begin. I have created a `daterange` table holding all dates between `2011-01-01` and `2011-08-30` to be able to CAOLESCE and return 0 for days missing in the `pageviews` table. But I'm quite lost from there onwards.

Do you know how to solve this? Any help is greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: See sundar's answer, AND you don't need the second table at all.  
Google "SQL date functions"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT DAY(_date),SUM(pageviews) FROM pageviews GROUP BY DAY(_date)
```

Hope the above query will solve the problem.

Comment: That won't give you the days that don't have pageviews.

Comment: @MyOtherMe How likely is it that a particular day of the month will have no views over a (long) period? Nobody is viewing your pages on the 13th of EACH month of the year? Why?

Comment: I think OP mentioned it saying "Notice there are days without any pageviews".

Comment: @GermannArlington: I agree that it is unlikely. But it is easier to spot the fact that the there is a total of 0 entries on the 13th of all months than it is to spot that there is no entry for the 13th at all.

Comment: @MyOtherMe You are right, but after running the query, there are no days without pageviews (when aggregated). Thanks @sundar!

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT a._date, SUM(IFNULL(b.pageviews, 0)) AS total_pageviews
FROM daterange a
     LEFT JOIN pageviews b
         ON DAYOFMONTH(a._date) = DAYOFMONTH(b._date)
GROUP BY DAYOFMONTH(a._date) 
ORDER BY a._date;
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
SELECT DAY(daterange._date),SUM(pageviews)
FROM daterange 
LEFT JOIN pageviews ON daterange._date = pageviews._date
GROUP BY DAY(daterange._date)
```